# Does the Draconic Aura feat improve by character level or class level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-advancement, class, character-levels

Let's say you're a silverbrown human and have the draconic aura feat. Normally you'd be stuck with a +1 aura, but since you have the dragonblood subtype, the feat states that:

> If you are of the dragonblood subtype, the bonus of your draconic
> aura improves with your class level. The aura grants a +2 bonus at 7th
> level, a +3 bonus at 14th level, and a +4 bonus at 20th level. [...]

The key word here is **class level** instead of **character level**. As we know, while those two might be equal, it might not be the case. Also, it should be noted that the feat has a "Character Level 3" requirement, so it seems a bit strange that the effects are keyed to class levels.

If said silverbrown human is multiclassing as wizard 5/full casting prestige class 5, should he select a class with which to progress his draconic aura? Or should we consider his total character level for the feat?

Answer (score 14):

This feat is **notoriously** poorly worded, so take everything about it with a grain of salt. It is probably better for a DM to just rule on it however they would like it to work, than to try to determine what they wrote and/or what they meant. For instance, tying this to *any* kind of class level is weird—we would usually use character level for this sort of thing, and that would make for a better game. The DM should value that far more than they should value whatever it is that they actually wrote.

Also, they made all kinds of errors in this feat, so honestly it might be safest to assume that **they** meant “character level,” **too**, and the “class level” thing itself is an error.

But if we do feel we must analyze the actual text, “your class level” is not a thing in D&D 3.5e, so there must have been some error somewhere. You have “class levels,” plural, or you have an “X class level” (or “class level in X” or whatever),  where X is some specified class. Since “class level,” singular and without a specified class, is not a defined term, or even a term that is used outside of this feat where we could compare its usage and context, we can’t really say it has **any** official meaning at all.

Is “your class level” your “class level in X” where X is any one class of your choice? Could be—but we don’t know. Is “your class level” equal to your total count of class levels, across all classes? Could be—but we don’t know. Is “your class level” something else entirely? Could be—but we don’t know.

Personally, I think reading “where X is any one class of your choice” into the feat where absolutely none of that text is present is a very great stretch. When you have a choice or decision to make, they’re *usually* pretty good about highlighting that fact. Since they do not indicate you have to choose a class here, I am inclined to reject that interpretation.

Using “your class level” to mean what other rules text refers to as “class levels,” that is, plural, makes much more sense to me. Consider:

> ##### Level Adjustment and Effective Character Level
>
> To determine the effective character level (ECL) of a monster character, add its level adjustment to its racial Hit Dice and character class levels.

<sup>([Monsters as Races](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monstersAsRaces.htm#levelAdjustmentandEffectiveCharacterLevel))</sup>

Here we see “character class levels” used as a single number in a calculation—this is the sense that I suspect Draconic Aura meant “your class level.” It’s inconsistent with the rest of the rules (which consistently refer to this in the plural), but it’s much closer to what they wrote than assuming they intended the selection of a single class.

Comment: While I understand your argument, I dont get the "tying this to any kind of class level is weird".

Comment: @RafaelLazzari Feat benefits usually aren’t, unless they’re directly related to a specific (named) class. Character level is both more common, and more sensible, in the context of a feat.

Answer (score -1):

I did more research after I posted the question, and I'm heavily inclined to the "it progress by class level", so I'm gonna go with Kryan's sugestion of ruling it myself, since I see way more evidence of it being the case of you needing to select a class to progress the feature.

While I did understand the argument made, I didn't get the "tying this to any kind of class level is weird", here's my reasoning:

Not only the classes that have auras as class features work that way (if a dragon shaman or a marshal multiclasses, they do not progress their auras), there are other examples that follow the same logic:

1 - If a cleric multiclasses his turning level do not progress (unless the class has a features that makes their level stack).

2 - If a wizard/sorcerer multiclasses into a class that do not grant a familiar, his familiar abilities do not progress.

We even have the obtain familiar feat (another feat that grants a class feature), it specifically states that only arcane caster classes count for improving it.

The only other example I could find the "Wild cohort" feat, which specifically states that it improves by "CHARACTER LEVEL".

Comment: Turn undead is a cleric class feature. A familiar is a sorcerer or wizard class feature. The Draconic Aura feat is not the feature of any class. **Very** different situation. Obtain Familiar is more similar, but again, it 1. defines (more-or-less) precisely which levels count, and 2. is based on a class feature. If Draconic Aura required you to already have draconic auras as a prerequisite, and said it was based on, say, your dragon shaman class level, then sure, that would make sense. But it’s specifically a feat for someone who has no relevant class levels to get a draconic aura.

Comment: Draconic Aura is the signature class feature of the dragon shaman class. As turn undead, familiar and animal companion are signature class features of the cleric, wizard and druid classes, that why I used them as comparison. Also, the draconic aura feat defines what should count: Class levels. I don't see many instances of designers confusing one for another as per the examples I just listed, thus I'm heavyly inclined to rule that the wording chose in the draconic aura feat description was not a mistake.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any other feat that is based on “class levels”—that is, all of them, but not racial hit dice—and even if that was their intent, I still label that a mistake, because it is inconsistent and also just a bad ruling. There is no reason why racial hit dice should be excluded. And I am not willing to trust the authors and editors of Draconic Aura much at all, considering how many (other) mistakes were made in that one feat. What’s one more? (For the record, though, I have not voted on this answer either way.)